# Cannot boot my BeagleBoard into Angstrom

Tags: beagleboard

I have an original BeagleBoard Rev C5 (**NOT xM**).
I followed this [tutorial](http://www.elinux.org/BeagleBoardBeginners) to boot it into linux, but I am stuck and need help solving this issue.
Currently I have two problems:

**First: **
When starting the board (connected to serial console) I get this:

```
Texas Instruments X-Loader 1.5.0 (Jun 14 2011 - 22:04:07)                                                                    
Beagle Rev C5                                                                                                                
Reading boot sector                                                                                                          
Loading u-boot.bin from mmc                                                                                                  

U-Boot 2011.03-rc1-00000-g9a3cc57-dirty (Apr 01 2011 - 17:41:42)                                                             

OMAP3530-GP ES3.1, CPU-OPP2, L3-165MHz, Max CPU Clock 720 mHz                                                                
OMAP3 Beagle board + LPDDR/NAND                                                                                              
I2C:   ready                                                                                                                 
DRAM:  256 MiB                                                                                                               
NAND:  512 MiB                                                                                                               
MMC:   OMAP SD/MMC: 0                                                                                                        
In:    serial                                                                                                                
Out:   serial                                                                                                                
Err:   serial                                                                                                                
Beagle Rev C4                                                                                                                
timed out in wait_for_pin: I2C_STAT=0                                                                                        
No EEPROM on expansion board                                                                                                 
Die ID #415a000400000000040398da01025012                                                                                     
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0                                                                                             
The user button is currently NOT pressed.                                                                                    
SD/MMC found on device 0                                                                                                     
usage: fatload <interface> <dev[:part]> <addr> <filename> [bytes]                                                            
Loading file "/boot/uImage" from mmc device 0:2 (xxa2)                                                                       
3203076 bytes read                                                                                                           
Booting from mmc ...                                                                                                         
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 80200000 ...                                                                          
   Image Name:   Angstrom/2.6.32/beagleboard                                                                                 
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)                                                                       
   Data Size:    3203012 Bytes = 3.1 MiB                                                                                     
   Load Address: 80008000                                                                                                    
   Entry Point:  80008000                                                                                                    
   Verifying Checksum ... OK                                                                                                 
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK                                                                                               
OK                                                                                                                           

Starting kernel ...                                                                                                          

Uncompressing    Linux..........................................................................................................
```

After that the above message restarts again over and over in an infinite loop.

**Second:**

When I connect the display through DVI interface, this message appears - also in a loop-

```
Texas Instruments X-Loader 1.5.0 (Jun 14 2011 - 22:04:07)                                                                    
Beagle Rev C5                                                                                                                
Reading boot sector                                                                                                          
Loading u-boot.bin from mmc                                                                                                  

U-Boot 2011.03-rc1-00000-g9a3cc57-dirty (Apr 01 2011 - 17:41:42)                                                             

OMAP3530-GP ES3.1, CPU-OPP2, L3-165MHz, Max CPU Clock 720 mHz                                                                
OMAP3 Beagle board + LPDDR/NAND                                                                                              
I2C:                                                                                                                       
Texas Instruments X-Loader 1.5.0 (Jun 14 2011 - 22:04:07)                                                                    
Beagle Rev C5
```

Any help, please!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem.

The answer was in the power supply, you should use a power supply that provides at least (5V-1A)...
USB OTG cable doesn't supply that much so board keeps rebooting